# Winforms. ObjectDataSource add calculated column

Tags: winforms, data-binding, aggregate, objectdatasource

I use ObjectDataSource and bind IEnumerable[Person] to my DevExpress GridView

```
class Person
{
   private int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

At grid there are two columns Id,Name. I want new column "Sum", which is calculated by person object(aggragate by person). At asp.net I create new column and calculate its value at RowDataBound event. At winforms I don't see this event and other appr. So what should I do in this case. Where can I handle binding moment? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make an [unbound column](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477) in your GridView, then calculate its value using the [`CustomUnboundColumnData`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic.aspx) event.